# Why is Javascript's `file.lastModified` not returning the original modification date but rather the upload date for uploaded files?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I am trying to access the last modification of files that are uploaded using http post. I thought this would be possible by setting an event listener on the upload button and saving the `lastModified` field like this:

```
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var modification_dates = [];
    var file_sizes = [];
    var file_types = [];
    var file_names = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      modification_dates.push(f.lastModified);
      file_sizes.push(f.size);
      file_types.push(f.type);
      file_names.push(f.name);
    }
    // Pass data to Django
    alert(Date(modification_dates[0]))
  }

  // Check for the various File API support.
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
  } else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
  }

  document.getElementById('id_file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

However if I upload a file that was last modified on the 15th of January 2019 the alert does not show this date but rather today's date:

[image: Alert window displays today's date instead of original modification date.]

How can I get the last modification date of the original file instead of the upload date?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are simply missing the `new` operator before `Date(modification_dates[0])`.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var modification_dates = [];
    var file_sizes = [];
    var file_types = [];
    var file_names = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      modification_dates.push(f.lastModified);
      file_sizes.push(f.size);
      file_types.push(f.type);
      file_names.push(f.name);
    }
    // Pass data to Django
    alert(new Date(modification_dates[0]))
  }

  // Check for the various File API support.
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
  } else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
  }

  document.getElementById('id_file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="id_file" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh really that is a very helpful information. I will check the size of files and come back here.

Comment: I just checked the `files` variable and it has the correct length of all selected files. So this seems not be the reason.

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem @Axel ; could you please check my updated answer?

Comment: Hi Daniele! Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. It seems like although `files` has the correct length `lastModified` is as you said not returning anything. All the other variables `file_size` etc. work as expected. Not sure why `lastModified` is not working.

Comment: @Axel https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/lastModified it seems to be compliant with all the browsers but internet explorer; are you using it? I'm using Chrome and if I press the "Run code snippet" button of my answer the alert shows the desired value. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's really confusing. I am using Firefox inside a Linux virtual machine. I assigned the bounty. I believe this is a system issue on my side. Thanks for your help!